# Global name 'variablename' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing my first Python script and get the error `NameError: global name 'board' is not defined`. Why is python throwing this error, and how can it be fixed?

```
class Screen(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def toggleLED(self, pressed):

        source = self.sender()

        if self.LedOn:
            source.setText('LED Off')
            self.LedOn = 0
            board.setHigh(13)
        else:           
            source.setText('LED On')
            self.LedOn = 1
            board.setLow(13)



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Screen()   
    board = Arduino('COM3')

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable called `board` is local to `main()` and is not visible inside the instance of the `Screen` class.

Perhaps the cleanest way to solve this is to let the instance of `Screen` keep a reference to `board`:

```
class Screen(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, board):

        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        self.board = board
        self.initUI()


    def toggleLED(self, pressed):

        source = self.sender()

        if self.LedOn:
            source.setText('LED Off')
            self.LedOn = 0
            self.board.setHigh(13)
        else:
            source.setText('LED On')
            self.LedOn = 1
            self.board.setLow(13)



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    board = Arduino('COM3')
    screen = Screen(board)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of lines in `toggleLED` that reference a variable called `board`, but `board` is never defined anywhere that it would be accessible within the scope of that method.

You probably want to pass the `board` object to the `Screen` when you create it, so that the `Screen` instance has a reference to the object. There are plenty of ways you can do this; if a board is essential to a `Screen`'s functionality, I'd put it in the initializer:

```
def __init__(self, board):
    super(Screen, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()
    self.board = board
```

Then you can refer to `self.board` wherever you need to access that instance (within the `Screen` class of course).